# php SESSION variables on bluehost

Tags: php, session, bluehost

Im having problems with my php SESSION varialbles 
my authentication system worked fine on my xampp server, and now im having problems since i moved over to bluehost

normally, if i open a page like index.php it checks to see if you are logged in, and if your not sends you to the login page, but that isn't working 
and just for testing i tried echoing the `$_SESSION['username']` and it turns up blank

now i did what ALEX said and i got this error:
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home7/.../public_html/blog.php:4) in /home7/blogboua/public_html/blog.php on line 22

here is the code:

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*-----Connect to Database-----*/
 include ('connect_database_2.php');

//check if logged in
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        return true;
    return false;
}


//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: login_form.html');
    die();
}

/* get username */
$username = $_SESSION['username'];


/*-----Include Navigation------*/
include ('frame.html');

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to send a `Location` header after you've already sent `<html><head>` on lines 2-3. You can't do that. Headers must be sent before any output is sent.

I honestly don't know how your code worked on your local server.

Comment: His code worked on the local server because it had output buffering configured. But this is the correct answer, I think. Solution is to move the `<html><head>` to immediately before the `include ('frame.html');`, or better yet put it inside `frame.html`.

Answer (score 1):

Set just inside the `<?php` of your `index.php`...

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Then reload `index.php` (the previously *blank page*).

It will tell you the cause for the error. Possibly, it could not write session data to `/tmp/`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a shared service provider like bluehost, then you need to be careful with your assumptions about the persistence of sessions as these hosting providers will garbage collect / cleanup old user /tmp files.  IMO, the easiest way to avoid this is to declare an explicit session handler and store your session context in your MySQL D/B.  See the [PHP session_save_handle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)r discussions for examples of how to do this.

Comment: i changed session.save_path to my own folder

Comment: "i changed session.save_path to my own folder" -- and added .htaccess access rules to stop them being accessible via URI, I hope :)

Comment: Just wanted to let everyone who suggested  setting session.save_path to a folder in one's own part of the file system for shared hosting servers that had chron jobs automatically nuking session variables after 20-30 minutes, that i too did this and it solved the problem of my mysteriously nuked sessions on bluehost. This has been driving me crazy for quite some time, incorrectly thinking the problem had something to do with faulty time keeping on shared servers.